# Why won't the widget display?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to create a GUI that displays a 5 by 3 grid, with each grid module being filled with one button. I created a class that makes the GUI below. When I run this the main window is how I expected but only the first widget is shown at the top left corner of the main window. The second widget never shows up. I looked all over the internet on this but nothing worked.

```
class choice_3_gui(Frame):
    def __init__(self): # Create the choice 3 GUI #
        ### --- Frame --- ###
            # Get Screen Dimensions #
        screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
        screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
            # Get GUI Dimensions #
        width = screen_width
        height = screen_height/2
            # Center the GUI #
        posx = (screen_width/2) - (width/2)
        posy = 0
            # Place the GUI #
        root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (width, height, posx, posy))
        ### --- Buttons --- ###
            # Area of Park #
        area_of_park_button = Button(root, text='AREA OF PARK', bg='white', fg='black', command=lambda: option_3_choice(1))
        area_of_park_button.grid(row=0, column=0)
            # Survey Date #
        survey_date_button = Button(root, text='SURVEY DATE', bg='white', fg='black', command=lambda: option_3_choice(2))
        area_of_park_button.grid(row=0,column=1)

        @staticmethod
        def option_3_index_choice(var):
            global option_3_choice
            option_3_choice = var
            root.destroy()
```

Comment: Please try to fix the formatting in your question. The code isn't properly formatted and is impossible to read.

Comment: `area_of_park_button.grid(row=0,column=1)` below `survey_date_button` creation should be `survey_date_button.grid(row=0,column=1)`.